# ListView in alphabetical order without Comparable

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, alphabetical

I'm trying to put this ListView in an alphabetical order by value of WORDS column. I've already read answers on this topic, but nevertheless haven't found any solution. Have I necessarily use Comparable/Comparator?

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> wordList;
private static final String WORD = "word";
private static final String DEFINITION = "definition";
private static final String NOTES = "notes";
private SimpleAdapter adapter;

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
final ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
wordList = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, Object> hm;

for (int i = word_counter - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    hm = new HashMap<>();
            hm.put(WORD, words[i]);
            hm.put(DEFINITION, definitions[i]);
            hm.put(NOTES, notes[i]);
            wordList.add(hm);
    } 

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, wordList,
    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{WORD, DEFINITION, NOTES},
    new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For auto sorting the data use **TreeSet**. TreeSet is a Collection in which the data you enter into it will be sorted regardless of the order you entered data into it.

```
    TreeSet ts=new TreeSet();
    for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        ts.add(words[i]+"-|-"+definitions[i]+"-|-"+notes[i]);
    }
    Iterator<String> itr=ts.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

The output will be in ascending order. From here, just split the string you get from the TreeSet using "-|-" as parameter for split(). And use each elements as you need.